Prestashop 8 is not calculating the discounts correctly
Prestashop is not calculating the discounts correctly. I have 3 cart rules established in such a way that they are 5% discount if it exceeds $1000, 2% more discount if it exceeds $2000 and 3% discount if it exceeds $3000 (that was my logic to be able to calculate discounts of 5% 7% and 10%). That could be happening?
Initially i would have to have a discount table like this:
5% discounts from 1000
7% between 2000 and 3000
and 10% from 3000
Could you help me see how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance
